# Ignore switchMap return value

Tags: rxjs

I want to resolve an observable but I don't want the return value to replace the previous value in the pipe. Is there any asynchronous `tap()`? I need an operator like a `switchMap` but I want to ignore the return.

```
of(1).pipe(switchMap(() => of(2))).subscribe(console.log); // expected: 1
```

I could create a custom operator but sure there's something built-in in rxjs.

Comment: `of(1).pipe(switchMap(value => concat(of(2).pipe(ignoreElements()), of(value))))` which could easily be turned into a user-land pipeable operator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up with this custom operator. It is like tap but resolves observables (and should be updated to also support promises).

```
export function switchTap<T, R>(next: (x: T) => Observable<R>): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T>;
export function switchTap<R>(observable: Observable<R>): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<R>;
export function switchTap<T, R>(
  arg: Observable<T>
  | ((x: T) => Observable<R>)
): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T>
{
  const next: (x: any) => Observable<T | R> = (typeof arg === 'function')
    ? arg
    : (x: any): Observable<T> => arg;

  return switchMap<T, T>(value => next(value).pipe(
    ignoreElements(),
    concat(of(value))
  ));
}
```

Usage:

```
of(1).pipe(
  switchTap(of(2))
).subscribe(console.log); // 1
```

or with a function:

```
of(1).pipe(
  switchTap(value => {
    console.log(value); // value: 1
    return of(value + 1);
  })
);
.subscribe(console.log); // 1
```

Comment: I think maybe your naming of 'switchTap' is confusing me (not that that is anything new with RxJs!). If you get a chance could you add an explanation of what this is actually for and a plain english description? Is the idea to 'wait' for the observable in the switchTap to complete (allowing it to receive the current value of whatever is in the pipe) and then continue. Maybe your original asyncTap is a better name if that's what it is doing? Also curious what you (or others) are actually using this for.

Comment: `switchTap` is the perfect name, because it correlates to the existing `switchMap` - you can read those docs and the purpose/name of this function will be clear.

Comment: How do you implement this custom operator?

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to simply ignore the values of the subscribe, then just don't pass in any arguments in the `subscribe` callback:

```
of(1).pipe(switchMap(() => of(2))).subscribe(()=>{
    console.log('no arguments')
});
```

If you however want to *retain* the values of the first observable, things can get tricky. One way is to use `Subject` to retain the value:

```
//create a BehaviorSubject
var cache = new BehaviorSubject<any>(0);

of(1).pipe(switchMap((first) => {
    cache.next(first);
    return of(2);
})).subscribe(() => {
    console.log(cache.value) //gives 1
});
```

Or you can use `.map()` to alter the values. This is kind of hacky and the code is harder to maintain:

```
of(1).pipe(switchMap((first) => {
    return of(2).map(() => first);
})).subscribe((second) => {
    console.log(second) //gives 1 because the values was mapped
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone new having the same problem I would advise using the `resultSelector` parameter supported by `switchMap` and other RxJS mapping operators.

**Example:**

```
switchMap(1 => of(2), (one, two) => one)
```

For further reading: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html

Comment: The `resultSelector` parameter is deprecated (since RxJS 6.0 I think?). The proposed alternative is to use a map operator on the inner observable (more or less like @CozyAzure shows in his last code snippet)

Answer (score 0):

I do it like so

```
of(2).pipe(
   switchMap( num => this.doSmtg(num), num => num)
).subscribe(num => console.log(num)); // 2
```

Second param of switchmap receives two value the one passed to this.doSmtg and the value returned by doSmtg(num)'s observable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `delayWhen` operator to achieve a similar functionality.

```
of(1)
  .pipe(
    delayWhen(value => {
      console.log(value); // value: 1
      return of(value + 1);
    })
  ).subscribe(console.log); // 1
```